# Account Kit (for Web) Server Error - We have encountered an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, account-kit

I tried to follow exactly the instructions here to set up account kit: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/web

However, whenever I try to login with email or SMS, I get a Server Error. The console displays this message:

IhKf9WP6cQ_.js:46 Refused to connect to 'https:// www.accountkit.com/ajax/bz' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src *.facebook.com *.fbcdn.net *.facebook.net *.spotilocal.com:* *.akamaihd.net wss://*.facebook.com:* https:// fb.scanandcleanlocal.com:* *.atlassolutions.com attachment.fbsbx.com ws:// localhost:* blob: *.cdninstagram.com chrome-extension:// boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd chrome-extension:// dliochdbjfkdbacpmhlcpmleaejidimm".

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like your browser is configured not to access certain domains - https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy and is blocking access to account kit and facebook.